# Is there a way to hide empty cells not rows from a DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I have a table with six rows, and seven columns.
the data is distributed in a way such that each row has an entry only under one single column and empty entries for the remaining six columns
I want to remove the empty cells so that i end up with only one row that has all the entries each under it's relevant column.
I tried to make a for loop and see if the cell is empty then set it's Visible property to false but i found out that the Visible property for the cells is only get with no set, so is there any way that i can hide the empty cells not the rows with empty cells ?

Thank you.

Comment: Think: How would an invisible cell __look__ like??? - Cells __cannot__ be invisble. DGV is a __grid__!

Comment: I think you are right, i am just wondering if it is possible to change the grid architecture, so that it is more about what is listed under each column rather than each row as an independent full record, that you can either remove completely or add completely

Comment: Nope. The grid layout doesn't consist of cells. It consists of columns and rows. You may consider a TableLayoutPanel. (But: I hate TLPs ,-)

Comment: yeah me too
Thank you for replying